# Extracting XML data from the packets

Tags: xml, http, tcp

I am trying to extract the TR069 XML data from the HTTP packets which I have filtered from a stream. The problem is the number of packets in a TCP flow are different. I cannot find an optimum filtering rule to terminate my XML extraction from a flow.Is there any kind of packet or keyword that is found at the end of the TCP stream?

Comment: Is there any kind of packet or keyword that is found at the end of the TCP stream? What has this to do with the subject or the XML tag?

Comment: There is no such thing as an HTTP packet.

Comment: @Dominik I am talking about the TCP port 80 addressed packets with XML in the raw payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP connection is closed to one direction by sending a FIN packet, and getting an ACK response. Similarly for the other direction. The connection may be closed for one direction and open for the other. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) has a nice description of TCP protocol operation.

Typically HTTP connection operates on top of a single TCP connection, such that the client closes the client -> server direction after sending the HTTP request and server closes server -> client direction after sending the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the `Content-Length` attribute from the HTTP header, then you know how many bytes to read until the end of the HTTP message.

Comment: I found it, it sends a HTTP 204 No Content, this is sent by both Client and the Server and later both ACK it. Thanks for the help.